# BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field and java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been researching on Hibernate 4 and Spring 4. I am getting this error and struggling with this for the past 4 days.
I have tried all the solutions in the internet for all these issues, but none of them worked. Please help me.

[Here is my project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC7Gi.png)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl] for bean with name 'trackDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl] for bean with name 'trackDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl] for bean with name 'trackDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:445)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)


Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl] for bean with name 'trackDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1440)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
    <artifactId>cumulis</artifactId>
    <name>CRUDWebApp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <java-version>1.8.0.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
  </properties>

   <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>Java.Net</id>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- To correct java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener error on Tomcat startup -->   
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!--  SLF4J seems to be required for Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--        Hibernate ORM framework dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bgee.log4jdbc-log4j2</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Our Logging mechanism is based on log4j2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my TrackController.java. I know that @Component annotation is redundant.

```
package com.cumulis.controller;

import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;   
import com.cumulis.dao.TrackDAO;
import com.cumulis.model.Track;
import com.cumulis.service.TrackService;

@Component
@Controller
public class TrackController {

    @Autowired
    private TrackDAO trackDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest() throws Exception {
        List<Track> trackList = trackDao.getAll();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("trackList");
        model.addObject("trackList", trackList);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newUser() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("trackForm");
        model.addObject("track", new Track());
        return model;      
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int trackId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Track track = trackDao.get(trackId);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("trackForm");
        model.addObject("track", track);
        return model;      
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        int trackId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        trackDao.delete(trackId);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");     
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveTrack(@ModelAttribute Track track) {
        trackDao.update(track);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }  
}
```

TrackDAOImpl.java

```
package com.cumulis.dao.impl;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.cumulis.dao.*;
import com.cumulis.model.*;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;

@Component
@Repository
public class TrackDAOImpl implements TrackDAO {


    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public TrackDAOImpl() {
    }

    public TrackDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView add(Track track) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(track);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Track get(long track_id){
         String hql = "from Track where id=" + track_id;
            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Track> trackList = (List<Track>) query.list();

            if (trackList != null && !trackList.isEmpty()) {
                return trackList.get(0);
            }  
            return null;
        //return (Track)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Track.class, track_id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(long track_id) {
        Track trackToDelete = new Track();
        trackToDelete.setId(track_id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(trackToDelete);
        //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(track_id);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(Track track) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(track);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public  List<Track>  getAll() {
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Track> trackList = (List<Track>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Track.class)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();

        return trackList;
    }

}
```

TrackDAO.java

```
package com.cumulis.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.cumulis.model.Track;

@Component
public interface TrackDAO {
    public ModelAndView add(Track track);
    public Track get(long track_id);
    public void delete(long track_id);
    public void update(Track track);
    public List<Track> getAll();
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.cumulis.model.Track" table="track">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the track highlight and entry point
         to other data found in subtrack and trackpoint. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>

      <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
      <property name="created" column="created" type="long"/>
      <property name="duration" column="duration" type="double"/>
      <property name="distance" column="distance" type="double"/>
      <property name="speed" column="speed" type="double"/>

   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

            <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

            <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
            <mvc:annotation-driven />

            <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
            <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

            <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.cumulis" />

            <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cumulis"/>
                <property name="username" value="root"/>
                <property name="password" value="xxxxxx"/>
            </bean> 

            <bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="packagesToScan">
                     <list>
                        <value>com.cumulis.controller</value>
                        <value>com.cumulis.dao</value>
                        <value>com.cumulis.dao.impl</value>
                        <value>com.cumulis.model</value>
                        <value>com.cumulis.service</value>
                        <value>com.cumulis.service.impl</value>
                     </list>
                </property>
                <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>

            <tx:annotation-driven />
            <bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            </bean>  

           <bean id="trackDAO" class="com.cumulis.dao.impl.TrackDAOImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>      

        </beans>
```

Comment: The problem is `ClassNotFoundException`. It means that the server/spring can't find your  `TrackDAOImpl`. How are you running your app?

Comment: Add @Autowired to your sessionFactory in the TrackDaoImpl class.

Comment: I am using Tomcat v8 server in eclipse IDE.

Comment: @Bill: I added that and am still getting NullPointerException at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:348)
.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of @Component from the following classes:

TrackDAO, TrackDAOImpl, TrackController

@Component is redundant since you are already using @Repository, @Controller etc.

Make sure you are also auto scanning the folders where the classes are located

You also have a weird combination between XML and Java Config. Choose one and stick with it, there is no need to have both running.

EDIT 1:
As requested link to example showing how to manually declare & auto scan for both XML and Java Config.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/

Comment: Please let me know what do you mean by " auto scanning the folders where the classes are located". I thought that I am using a pure XML based strategy by injecting the session factory.  Could you kindly clarify your comment?

Comment: You are using Java Config as well as XML config. You need to be consistant and choose firstly which method you want to use, then code based on it. Instead of manually declaring the beans you should auto scan them into existanct, have a look at the edit for good example how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes worked.
 @Controller
        public class TrackController {

```
        @Autowired
        private TrackDAO trackDao;

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public ModelAndView handleRequest() throws Exception {
            List<Track> trackList = trackDao.getAll();
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("trackList");
            model.addObject("trackList", trackList);
            return model;
        }
...
```

and

```
    @Repository("TrackDAOImpl")
    public class TrackDAOImpl implements TrackDAO {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Autowired
        public TrackDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public  List<Track>  getAll() {
             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Track> trackList = (List<Track>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(Track.class)
                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();

            return trackList;
        }
...
```

I also had to remove multiple hibernate-annotation jars. I also had to change this in servlet-context.xml.

```
<bean id="TrackDAOImpl" class="com.cumulis.dao.TrackDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```